# working on simple HTML table columns parsing

Tags: python, html, lxml, html-table, tablerow

I am working on HTML tables using python.

I want to know that how can i fetch different column values using lxml?

HTML table :

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Header_1</td>
<td>Header_2</td>
<td>Header_3</td>
<td>Header_4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 1_cell 1</td>
<td>row 1_cell 2</td>
<td>row 1_cell 3</td>
<td>row 1_cell 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2_cell 1</td>
<td>row 2_cell 2</td>
<td>row 1_cell 3</td>
<td>row 1_cell 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 3_cell 1</td>
<td>row 3_cell 2</td>
<td>row 1_cell 3</td>
<td>row 1_cell 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 4_cell 1</td>
<td>row 4_cell 2</td>
<td>row 1_cell 3</td>
<td>row 1_cell 4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and I am looking to get output as :

```
[
[
('Header_1', 'Header_2'),
('row 1_cell 1', 'row 1_cell 2'),
('row 2_cell 1', 'row 2_cell 2'),
('row 3_cell 1', 'row 3_cell 2'),
('row 4_cell 1', 'row 4_cell 2')
],
[
('Header_1', 'Header_3'),
('row 1_cell 1', 'row 1_cell 3'),
('row 2_cell 1', 'row 2_cell 3'),
('row 3_cell 1', 'row 3_cell 2'),
('row 4_cell 1', 'row 4_cell 3')
]
]
```

how can i fetch such different column and their values?

Comment: can you use XML with XSLT to parse and transform the result?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary : where is solution?

Comment: @sam deleted due to downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how do you make the choice of Header1+Header2, or Header1+Header3,...  As the tables must be reasonably small, I suggest to collect all the data, and only then to extract the wanted subsets of the table.  The following code show the possible solution:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

def parseTable(table_fragment):
    header = None   # init - only to create the variable (name)
    rows = []       # init

    # Parse the table with lxml (the standard xml.etree.ElementTree would be also fine).
    tab = ET.fromstring(table_fragment)
    for tr in tab:
        lst = []
        if header is None:
            header = lst
        else:
            rows.append(lst)

        for e in tr:
            lst.append(e.text)

    return header, rows


def extractColumns(header, rows, clst):
    header2 = []
    for i in clst:
        header2.append(header[i - 1])   # one-based to zero-based

    rows2 = []
    for row in rows:
        lst = []
        rows2.append(lst)
        for i in clst:
            lst.append(row[i - 1])      # one-based to zero-based

    return header2, rows2


def myRepr(header, rows):
    out = [repr(tuple(header))]         # init -- list with header
    for row in rows:
        out.append(repr(tuple(row)))    # another row
    return '[\n' + (',\n'.join(out)) + '\n]'   # join to string



table_fragment = '''\
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Header_1</td>
<td>Header_2</td>
<td>Header_3</td>
<td>Header_4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 1_cell 1</td>
<td>row 1_cell 2</td>
<td>row 1_cell 3</td>
<td>row 1_cell 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2_cell 1</td>
<td>row 2_cell 2</td>
<td>row 1_cell 3</td>
<td>row 1_cell 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 3_cell 1</td>
<td>row 3_cell 2</td>
<td>row 1_cell 3</td>
<td>row 1_cell 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 4_cell 1</td>
<td>row 4_cell 2</td>
<td>row 1_cell 3</td>
<td>row 1_cell 4</td>
</tr>
</table>'''


# Parse the table
header, rows = parseTable(table_fragment)

# For debugging...
print header
print rows

# Collect the representations of the selections.  The extractColumns() 
# returns a tuple.  The * expands it to two arguments.
lst = []
lst.append(myRepr(header, rows))
lst.append(myRepr(*extractColumns(header, rows, [1, 2])))
lst.append(myRepr(*extractColumns(header, rows, [1, 3])))
lst.append(myRepr(*extractColumns(header, rows, [1, 2, 4])))

# Write the output.
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('[\n')
    f.write(',\n'.join(lst))
    f.write('\n]')
```

The output.txt now contains:

```
[
[
('Header_1', 'Header_2', 'Header_3', 'Header_4'),
('row 1_cell 1', 'row 1_cell 2', 'row 1_cell 3', 'row 1_cell 4'),
('row 2_cell 1', 'row 2_cell 2', 'row 1_cell 3', 'row 1_cell 4'),
('row 3_cell 1', 'row 3_cell 2', 'row 1_cell 3', 'row 1_cell 4'),
('row 4_cell 1', 'row 4_cell 2', 'row 1_cell 3', 'row 1_cell 4')
],
[
('Header_1', 'Header_2'),
('row 1_cell 1', 'row 1_cell 2'),
('row 2_cell 1', 'row 2_cell 2'),
('row 3_cell 1', 'row 3_cell 2'),
('row 4_cell 1', 'row 4_cell 2')
],
[
('Header_1', 'Header_3'),
('row 1_cell 1', 'row 1_cell 3'),
('row 2_cell 1', 'row 1_cell 3'),
('row 3_cell 1', 'row 1_cell 3'),
('row 4_cell 1', 'row 1_cell 3')
],
[
('Header_1', 'Header_2', 'Header_4'),
('row 1_cell 1', 'row 1_cell 2', 'row 1_cell 4'),
('row 2_cell 1', 'row 2_cell 2', 'row 1_cell 4'),
('row 3_cell 1', 'row 3_cell 2', 'row 1_cell 4'),
('row 4_cell 1', 'row 4_cell 2', 'row 1_cell 4')
]
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Look into LXML as an html/xml parser that you could use.  Then simply make a recursive function.